# finite integral domain algebras are division algebras

Tags: division-algebras

If R is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field k, and if R is also 
an integral domain, show that R is a division algebra over k.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/proof-that-an-integral-domain-that-is-a-finite-dimensional-f-vector-space-is-i

Answer (score 1):

If $a\in R$ then $$x\mapsto ax$$ is a linear transform, it is injective since $R$ is an integral domain. It is surjective since $R$ is finite dimensional. Therefore $1$ is in the image. Similar for right multiplication by $a$.