# $R$ be a commutative ring which is a vector space over some field $F$ , is the map $f(x)=rx , \forall x \in R$ $F$- linear for every $r \in R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Let $R$ be a commutative ring which is a vector space over some field $F$ ; for $r \in R$ consider the function $f:R \to R$ defined as $f(x)=rx , \forall x \in R$  , is this function a vector space homomorphism i.e. is it a linear map ? I can easily verify the additivity but having trouble with the homogeneity ; I have calculated for $\alpha \in F$ , $f(\alpha . x)= r(\alpha .x)=(\alpha . x)r$ and $\alpha . f(x)=\alpha .(rx)=\alpha . (xr)$ , but cannot see how they are equal . Please help .

Comment: ring multiplication is associative.

Comment: @MooS : that is completely ok , but how can I say $\alpha . (xr)=(\alpha . x)r$ ? first of all $\alpha $ I don't know whether is in $R$ or not and second of all '$.$' , the external scalar product , is different from ring multiplication . Am I making any mistakes ?

Comment: So you do not require $R$ to be a $F$-Algebra?

Comment: @MooS :  actually I was having trouble in understanding the second answer to this question   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/proof-that-an-integral-domain-that-is-a-finite-dimensional-f-vector-space-is-i .... this is my primary query

Comment: In this case we have $1 \in R$ since $R$ is an integral domain and we get $F \subset R$ via $F \cong F \cdot 1 \subset R$. So the scalar multiplication $F \times R \to R$ is just the restriction of the ring multiplication $R \times R \to R$.

Comment: @MooS : How is $F.1 \subset R$ and what is this "$.$" here ?

Comment: $F.1$ denotes the $F$-subspace spanned by the vector $1$.

Comment: @MooS: So , we define $\alpha . x := (\alpha .1)x$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: @MooS : THANKS  a lot , that truly helped , thank you .

Comment: @MooS Please consider converting your comments into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).