# Finitely generated subalgebras of an algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain

Let $k$ be a field and $\bar{k}/k$ be an algebraic closure of $k$. Let $k'$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, which is a subalgebra of $\bar{k}$. Is it true that $k'$ is a finite field extension of $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $k'$ is finitely generated and integral over $k$, hence finite over $k$ ([Stacks/02JJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JJ)). It is then a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space and an integral domain, hence a field ([Stacks/00GS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GS)).

Comment: (+1) Perhaps more readable than the second link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4357501/386889

Comment: Yes. I assume this has been proven > 20 times on MSE. :-)
Cheers!